# Over-riding the background() function in p5.js?

Tags: graphics, background, processing, p5.js

I made a galaxy sketch in p5.js using rotates and radians, but it's erased each time the background() is loaded as draw() runs. Is there a way to over-ride the background() function? I want the galaxies to remain in view.

```javascript
 var stars;

function preload(){
//for (var i = 0; i < planetArray.length; i++) {
//stars = loadImage('Assets/stars.png');
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

}
function draw() {
  //background(0);
  star()
  //function mousepressed(){
}
  function star(){
  //angle = map(mouseX, 0,width, 0,360);
  //rotate(radians(angle*100));  
  noStroke();
  //translate(width/2, height/2);
  translate(mouseX,mouseY);
  fill(0);
  rotate(radians(frameCount%360)); //rotates output of ellipses
  rotate(radians(1000*frameCount%360));
  for(var i =0; i < 20; i++){
    push();
    noStroke();
    fill(random(200),0,random(150),random(2));
   // fill(random(125),random(250),random(100));
    ellipse(10*frameCount % (width/10),0,10,10);
    //image(stars, 10*frameCount % (width/2),0,10,10)
    //image((10*frameCount % (width/2),0,10,10)
    //
    pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there really isn't any magic to it. Calling the `background()` function fills the window with a solid color (or image) and draws over anything you've previously drawn.

The solution to this problem isn't to "over-ride" the `background()` function. It's to restructure your program so your stuff gets drawn properly. Exactly how you do that depends on exactly what you want to happen.

**Option 1:** Only call the `background()` function once.

If you just want a black background at the beginning, and everything you do from the `draw()` function should still add up, then maybe you just want to call the `background()` function once. You could do it as the last line in your `setup()` function, for example.

**Option 2:** Store everything you want to draw in a data structure.

This is probably the most typical case. If you want a background to be drawn behind shapes that are moving around, you're going to have to store those shapes in some kind of data structure, and then draw all of them every single frame.

**Option 3:** Draw to an off-screen image, and then draw that image on top of your background.

This is a bit of a mix between the first two options. You can draw everything (except the background) to an off-screen `PImage`, and then draw the background to the screen, then draw the image to the screen. This allows you to have a background that changes colors without having to redraw everything else.

Which option you choose really depends on exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: Thank you! I put it in setup() and everything looks great. I wish I could fedEx you cupcakes.

Comment: Ha! Thanks. I'm not sure cupcakes would travel very well through the mail though!