# Rotating/Turning Groups of Ellipses

Tags: graphics, rotation, p5.js

I'm working on a project where I create mini galaxies using ellipses, rotate, radians, etc. on mouseX and mouseY. However, I'd love it if each mini galaxy could rotate left or right, so that it looks like a galaxy turning slowly in space. Not sure how I'd do this, though, and would love some guidance. Do I have to create an array that holds the ellipses for each galaxy, and then somehow rotate that? Can I simply set a rotate() for each individual ellipse as it draws to the screen? Thanks for any help!

```
var bgimg;

function preload(){
//for (var i = 0; i < planetArray.length; i++) {
bgimg = loadImage('Assets/galaxy_background.jpg');
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(1301, 822);
  background(bgimg, 100);
  //background(25,25,22);

}
function draw() {
  //background(0);
  fill(255);
  noStroke();
  textSize(19);
  text("Create mini-galaxies by holding your mouse in a location. Move to create another.", 20, 40);
  star()
  //function mousepressed(){
}
  function star(){
  //angle = map(mouseX, 0,width, 0,360);
  //rotate(radians(angle*100));  
  noStroke();
  //translate(width/2, height/2);
  translate(mouseX,mouseY);
  fill(0);
  rotate(radians(frameCount%360)); //rotates output of ellipses
  rotate(radians(1000*frameCount%360));
  for(var i =0; i < 20; i++){
    push();
    noStroke();
    tint(255, 127); 
    fill(random(230),5,random(210),random(230));
   // fill(random(125),random(250),random(100));
    ellipse(10*frameCount % (width/20),0,5,5);
    rotate(radians(mouseX, mouseY));
    //image(stars, 10*frameCount % (width/2),0,10,10)
    //image((10*frameCount % (width/2),0,10,10)
    //
    pop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have better luck with your questions if you try to narrow them down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting your full sketch. It's hard to answer general "how do I do this" type questions. It's much easier to answer specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type question. That being said, I'll try to answer in a general sense:

You're having trouble because of the fact that you're letting your drawing accumulate by only calling the `background()` function once instead of clearing it every frame. There's nothing wrong with this, but it does make it impossible to apply transforms and rotations to stuff you've already drawn.

Like I said in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989216/how-can-i-over-ride-the-background-function-in-p5-js), most Processing sketches do this:

**Store everything you need to draw in a data structure.**

You might store an array of `PVectors`. Or you might create a `Galaxy` class that contains variables and functions that allow it to draw itself, which you call from your `draw()` function. The data structure you use is entirely up to you.

[This page](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/JavaScript-basics) and [this page](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Processing-transition) contain discussions on creating objects in p5.js, or you might just try a google search. [Here](https://p5js.org/examples/examples/Objects_Objects.php) is an example that uses a class that knows how to draw itself, and then creates an instance of that class to create a sketch.

**Clear previous frames every time `draw()` is called.**

Most sketches call the `background()` function every frame. That might seem annoying because then you have to redraw everything, but that's what the data structures are for.

**Redraw everything you want to be drawn every frame.**

Iterate over those data structures and redraw your scene. This might be as simple as iterating over an array of `PVectors`, or maybe you'll want to create objects that know how to draw themselves.

Like I said, this is very general, and exactly what you do depends on how you think about all of the above. There isn't a single best way to do this, so it's hard to be more specific.